# Query record when N values of a column are present

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar to the one shown in snip. I want to Query all the Facility_name and Product_Id for which all 'Week' exist i.e. 1,2,3

[image]

Desired output would be only 'A' Faility_Name and respective Product_Id, as for them we have all 3 Weeks available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Facility_name 
FROM source_table
GROUP BY Facility_name 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `Week`) = ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `Week`) 
                                  FROM source_table )
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM source_table 
JOIN ( SELECT Facility_name 
       FROM source_table
       GROUP BY Facility_name 
       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `Week`) = ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `Week`) 
                                         FROM source_table ) ) subquery USING (Facility_name)
```

If your MySQL version is 8+ then move subqueries to CTE.

Comment: Tried the 1st one but got only 1 record i.e. the very first one

Comment: @user13325679 1st query returns only `Facility_name` which matches. 2nd returns all separate records which's `Facility_name` matches.

Answer (score 0):

This is the 4th question I've ran across in a month about querying parents (`facility_name`) for containing, at least, a specific sub-set of tags ( `Week` ).

For reference, [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/267559/how-to-filter-multiple-many-to-many-relationship-based-on-multiple-tags) is one of the posts on DBA SE with my answer.

The solution:

1. Find all the required matches
2. ensure that you have the correct cardinality.

This question required `COUNT(distinct)` instead of `COUNT(*)` (as shown in the other post).

Your schema was simple enough to put into DB Fiddle to validate.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
create table source_table ( Facility_name varchar(1), product_id varchar(2), `Week` int);

insert into source_table values
 ('A', 'A1', 1),
 ('A', 'A1', 1),
 ('A', 'A2', 2),
 ('A', 'A3', 3),
 ('B', 'B1', 1),
 ('B', 'B2', 2),
 ('C', 'B3', 3),
 ('C', 'C1', 1),
 ('D', 'D1', 2);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
with query_these_weeks as (
  select 1 as `Week` union all
  select 2 as `Week` union all
  select 3 as `Week`
)
select Facility_name
from source_table as a
  join query_these_weeks as b on a.`Week` = b.`Week`
group by Facility_name
having count(distinct a.`Week`) = (select count(*) from query_these_weeks);
```

```
| Facility_name |
| ------------- |
| A             |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/0)